# Access docker volume files from different container running .Net core

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I have a docker compose that runs many containers including a container with .Net core code and a dd-agent container.

I have noticed that dd-agent container uses a volume and I need to access files in that volume using code running in the other container.

I have tried to use:

```
var path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var root = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
var files = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.log", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

but the files list doesn't contain the files I can see in volume when running something like:

```
docker run --rm -i -v=myvolume:/tmp/myvolume busybox find /tmp/myvolume
```

Any ideas on how I can get the volume files?

Docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"
volumes:
  logs:
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    container_name: localstack
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3,dynamodb
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
      - HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL=localstack
      - HOSTNAME=localstack
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=test
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=test
    ports:
      - "4572:4572"
      - "4569:4569"
  aws-cli:
    container_name: aws-cli
    image: mesosphere/aws-cli
    volumes:
      - ./../script:/script
    environment:
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=test
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=test
    entrypoint: /script/aws.sh
    depends_on:
      - localstack
  dd-agent:
    container_name: dd-agent
    image: datadog/agent:latest
    ports:
      - "8126:8126"
    environment:
      - DD_APM_ENV=test
      - DD_API_KEY={}
      - DD_PROCESS_AGENT_ENABLED=true
      - DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC=true
      - DD_APM_ENABLED=true
      - DD_APM_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC=true
      - DD_LOG_LEVEL=info
      - DD_HOSTNAME=datadoghq
    volumes:
      - logs:/var/log/datadog
  myapi:
    container_name: myapi
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      target: final
      args:
        RELEASETYPE: "Debug"
      context: ./../
      dockerfile: path/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - DD_AGENT_HOST=dd-agent
      - DD_ENV=test
      - DD_LOGS_INJECTION=true
      - DD_SERVICE_NAME=test
      - DD_TRACE_AGENT_PORT=8126
      - DD_TRACE_AGENT_URL=http://dd-agent:8126
      - DD_TRACE_DEBUG=true
      - DD_TRACE_ENABLED=true
      - DD_TRACE_LOG_PATH=/var/log/datadog/dotnet-profiler.log
      - FLUENTD_PORT=24224
      - FLUENTD_RETRIES=3
    volumes:
      - logs:/var/log/datadog
      - type: bind
        source: ../src
        target: /src/src
    ports:
      - 1990:80
    depends_on:
      - aws-cli
```

Comment: You need to mount the same volume into both containers.  If you're trying to do things via direct `docker run` commands note that Compose will rename things like volumes and networks so you'll need a command like `docker volume ls` to find the actual volume name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can access files of one container from another container. Even with `docker cp` you can only copy files from the container to the host. Copying from container to container is also not allowed. I would suggest mounting a common volume for the files you want to access. That way you can access them using the mounted folder in the host as an intermediary

```
service:
    
    service1:
        volumes:
            - ./temp_on_host:/path-to-the-directory-you-want-to-access-through-code
    
   service2:
        volumes:
           - ./temp_on_host:/any_path_in_the_container_which_your_code_can_access
```

Now the code in your service2 can indirectly access the files in the specified directory in service1

Comment: when using shared volume, dd-agent container still writes files to a random volume it creates, can I get that shared?

Comment: yes, just mount some common volume on host and connect the two directories in the respective containers. Not sure if the best way to do it, but its one way.

Comment: post your docker-compose for more details

Comment: I have posted my docker-compose, I see that logs volume is shared and linked to by 2 containers, but it is empty and dd-agent is using different auto created volume

Comment: what is logs here? try creating a file in logs and see if its reflected inside the mapped directory of the container. Tell me if that works. I think you should give the path like ./logs or ../logs or something like that

Comment: I added files from my service side and I can see the files in volume, but I want it the opposite way, files written by dd-agent should go to my volume as well

Comment: Yes, files written by your dd-agent also go into the volume. You can confirm that by creating a file inside dd-agent service